# How to create action sheet for imagePickerController based on following image?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

On click of a button i have to upload image to the server. Here i know how to code for camera and gallery. But i don't no how to write for google photos and dropbox. how it can be done. The action sheet should also be like the  uploaded,

[image: like this]

and is it possible to show popup like the image shown without using third party Api's?

Comment: you need to call from SDK of dropbox and google photos and get all data from dropbox and google photos

Comment: It means I have to integrate both Dropbox and googlephotos?

Comment: Yes u need to integrate both sdk.

Comment: but for google photos i cant find any sdk's

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/ refer this link for photos

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Google Photos and Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios) SDKs